# how do i fix undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to start my server after a db:migrate:reset and suddenly my SQlite3 server will not start. I get the error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass)` when the server begins to render my `datum/index` page.
Before i did this i had actual prices in my database so the user_id could be detected and everything worked but now since the prices are gone i believe its giving this error.

**Controllers** - `Datum` & `Price`:

```
def index
  @prices = Price.all
end
```

**Views** - `datum/index` & `prices/index`:

```
<h1>Prices</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Price name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @prices.each do |price| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= price.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= price.date %></td>
    <td><%= price.price_name %></td>
    <td><%= price.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_price_path(price) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', price, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Price', new_price_path %>
```

I think i am doing this the wrong way as i am new to Rails. My goal was to duplicate my `prices/index` view so my `datum/index` is the same so i could then give both unique looks. **How do i correct this issue and am i doing this correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, i think it was giving this error because i was using AptanaStudio 3 with the git terminal. I just restarted everything and it started working now as if the Database needed time to refresh itself. So in conclusion **just restart everything** and see if it works then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you don't know what `rake db:migrate:reset` does. There's no description string for it so don't ask `rake` what it does, you have to [look at the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L173):

```
# desc 'Resets your database using your migrations for the current environment'
task :reset => ['db:drop', 'db:create', 'db:migrate']
```

So `rake db:migrate:reset` destroys your database (including any data you had in it), recreates it, and then applies the migrations to bring everything up to date again. But, all your original data is still gone.

The `db:drop` part of `db:migrate:reset` probably explains why you're getting `nil` all over the place. However, you should be getting an empty array from `Price.all` if all your data was gone so perhaps you've added something after your reset.

Comment: But in that case, `Price.all` will be `[]` and the loop `@prices.each do |price|` will not be executed, i.e. it will not enter the loop. Then how is this error coming?

Comment: The only things i added were a category migration and a search migration. That couldn't be the reason.

Comment: @JustinRoR: Have you poked around your SQLite database manually to see what's in there?

Comment: @rubyprince: Hence the "you should be getting an empty array from Price.all if all your data was gone so perhaps you've added something after your reset" at the bottom.